# how to test ajax request in custom component made by polymer

Tags: polymer, wct

component html file part where request is being send

```
       <paper-button class="indigo" style="margin-top:1em; width:15%" 
        on-tap="sendLoginRequest">Login</paper-button>
         <iron-ajax id="loginAjaxRequest" handle-as="json" on- 
     response="loginResponse" on-error="showToast"></iron-ajax>
```

sendloginRequest function part where request is fired

```
        sendLoginRequest() {
         //some code
   this.$.loginAjaxRequest.url = "http://localhost:8080/api/login"
    this.$.loginAjaxRequest.body = JSON.stringify(loginJson)
    this.$.loginAjaxRequest.method = "POST"
    this.$.loginAjaxRequest.generateRequest()
  }
```

how to write test cases for it

Comment: Please be more specific in the question. What type of tests, ect.

Comment: writing wct tests

Comment: i am getting these kind of logs after runnning polymer test command Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
:8081/bower_components/scheduler-component/scheduler-component.html:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
:8081/bower_components/paper-dialog/paper-dialog.html:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
:8081/bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Alright well you are going to have to double check your paths and other data you put in for your requests.  You haven't put in enough information to give a proper answer to your question.  You should probably use a simple case scenario that reproduces the error.

Comment: Maybe you'll be able to resolve it on your own if you did.